# incorrect array calculations in the second loop

Tags: java, arrays

When I do the calculations in the second for loop it does not calculate properly.
I will only calculate the last number in the array and not the other two.
The if block calculation are correct. What I need to do then is to take each 
[row][col] value and divide that by temp3 and display it in the array.
Please advice.
Thank you in advance.
Avi

```
package tester;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{      
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("one.txt"));

    float [][] glassdata = new float[3][4];

    loadArray(glassdata, inFile);
    displayArray(glassdata);

    System.out.println("\n***************\n");

    normalizingVector(glassdata);
}

public static void loadArray(float [][] g, Scanner inFile)
{
    for(int row = 0; row < g.length; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < g[row].length; col++)
        {
           g[row][col] = inFile.nextFloat();
        }
    }      
}

public static void displayArray(float [][] g)   
{
    for(int row = 0; row < g.length; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 1; col < g[row].length; col++)
        {
            System.out.print(g[row][col] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void normalizingVector(float [][] g)
{
    float temp1 = 0;
    float temp2 = 0;
    float temp3 = 0;
    float temp4 = 0;


    for (int row = 0; row < g.length; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 1; col < g[row].length; col++)
        {
            if(col < g[row].length)
            {
                temp1 = (float) Math.pow(g[row][col], 2);               
                temp2 = temp2 + temp1;
            }
            temp3 = (float) Math.sqrt(temp2);
            temp4 = (g[row][col]) / temp3;
            //System.out.print((g[row][col] / temp3) + " ");
            System.out.print(temp4 + " ");
        }
        //System.out.print(temp3);
        System.out.println();
        temp1 = 0;
        temp2 = 0;
        temp3 = 0;
        temp4 = 0;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you add an example of input, expected output and actual output?

Comment: You have written, that you need to take each [row][col] value, but in normalizingVector method you start your column interation from the second value (i.e. starting col index equals to 1). Is this behavior implemented on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Your `normalizingVector` method has some redundancy to it and does essentially nothing. The only values being assigned are `temp1`, `temp2`, `temp3` and `temp4` which are local and set back to 0 at every iteration of the for-loop.

I've rewritten your code a bit: It only uses one temporary variable now which is set to 0 at the start of every iteration of the outer loop (you could also do that at the end, but in my eyes it makes your code easier to read if you do it at the start). 
Note that `temp1` is 0 initially and increments by the square value of the accessed array element each iteration. 
A statement of the form `t += a` stands short for `t = t + a`. I've used that to simplify the code a bit.

```
public static void normalizingVector(float [][] g)
{
float temp1;

for (int row = 0; row < g.length; row++)
{
    temp1 = 0;
    //col should start from 0, unless you intended that
    for(int col = 0; col < g[row].length; col++)
        temp1 += (float) Math.pow(g[row][col], 2);
    temp1 = (float) Math.sqrt(temp1);               
    for(int col = 0; col < g[row].length; col++)
        g[row][col] = g[row][col] / Math.sqrt(temp1);
}}
```

You need to add a second inner for loop because, when normalizing a vector, you want every element of the vector to be divided by its length.